# Qual è il significato di "prendere i cinque minuti"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Certo, il padre, Fernando lo scarparo, quando **gli prendevano i cinque minuti** diventava cattivo. Ma a tutti i padri venivano le furie. Tanto più che il suo, quando lei non lo provocava, era un uomo gentile, simpatico, gran lavoratore.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "prendere i cinque minuti" in questo brano. L'ho cercata nel Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli, ma non l'ho trovata. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: ***Cinque minuti***: http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cinque-minuti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Significa arrabbiarsi, perdere la pazienza.

Spesso è più conveniente cercare espressioni usando un motore di ricerca e mirando la ricerca ad un sito (può essere quello della Treccani o altro di tua preferenza) in questo modo arrivi a risultati utili che ti sarebbe difficile trovare usando le funzioni di ricerca del sito stesso.

Questo, per esempio, lo si trova nel Treccani a riguardo della parola "[ribollire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ribollire_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)" (è solo un esempio di come puoi scavare un poco in profondità per le tue ricerche, l'espressione appare in altre parti del sito):

> ● Espressioni: sentirsi ribollire il sangue [sentirsi molto nervoso] ≈ adirarsi, arrabbiarsi, (fam.) ***farsi venire i cinque minuti***, inalberarsi, (volg.) incazzarsi, incollerirsi. ↑ andare in bestia (o su tutte le furie), imbestialirsi, imbufalirsi.

In teatro "dare i cinque minuti" invece avverte che ci sono 5 minuti prima di entrare in scena

Comment: Avevo anche cercato il significato dell'espressione su Google (lo faccio di solito), ma non avevo trovato niente.

Comment: @Charo, dipende da come cerchi. Prova ad isolare la parte essenziale di un'espressione e cercare quella se tutta l'espressione completa non ti dà risultati e mantieni il motore di ricerca mirato solo al sito di tua preferenza. In questo caso il verbo può cambiare visto che i cinque minuti possono prendergli, venirgli, saltargli ecc... quindi quello lo scarti e cerchi il resto come espressione esatta (tra virgolette).